# How to add the confusion matrix and precision metric to this experiment?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter, random-forest

I am making and experiment of machine learning using Python the thing is that I would like to add the precisión metric and confusion matrix to my experiment my complete code look as follows:

```
print('Random Forest Testing')

from sklearn import svm
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import csv
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

opening csv:

```
f = open('Telcel_facebook_comments_train.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
```

creating a vectorizer tfidf:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char',ngram_range=(1, 3))
```

list to keep the comments and labels:

```
list_comments=[]
list_tags=[]
for row in csv_f:
    list_comments.append(row[0])
    list_tags.append(row[1])        
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(list_comments)
print(X)
vectorizadorEtiquetas= preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
Y=vectorizadorEtiquetas.fit_transform(list_tags)
print(Y)
```

Getting the name of the features:

```
tfidf_words=vectorizer.get_feature_names()
clf = svm.SVR()
#Second Machine learning algorithm 
clf2 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
clf2 = clf2.fit(X, Y)
#building X train and Y train matrix
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=47)
print('Starting training')
#clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf2.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Training Completed')
print(clf2.score(X_test, y_test))
```

importing Confusion Matrix and recall

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
```

Here is when I need to add the precision and confusion matrix, the following code is wrong since I dont know how to get the matrix called "y_true", I just have three class that are: 1,2,3

```
print(precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred, average='macro'))
print(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred))
```

besides to be more clear this is a part of the output:

```
Random Forest Testing
  (0, 2128) 0.225797583675
  (0, 6205) 0.243191128615
  (0, 6366) 0.21798642306
  (0, 3292) 0.204253719304
  (0, 4763) 0.161726027808
  (0, 1950) 0.264734992986
  (0, 6457) 0.264734992986
  (0, 5153) 0.264734992986
  (0, 3216) 0.105568550619
  (0, 4760) 0.128342578419


[3 1 1 ..., 2 2 2]
Starting training
Training Completed
0.881481481481
```

However I would like to appreciate support to show the confussion matrix and recall metric to understand more of my model, thanks for the support.

This is my second effort to achieve the result, Now instead of the lines above I tried:

```
y_pred = clf2.predict(X_test)
print('Training Completed')


'''
Returns the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.
In multi-label classification, this is the subset accuracy which is a harsh metric since you
require for each samplethat each label set be correctly predicted.
'''

print(clf2.score(X_test, y_test))

#importing Confusion Matrix and recall
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

#Here is when I need to add the precision and confusion matrix
print(precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, y_pred, average='macro'))

print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```

and this is the output:

```
(0.68431620945676808, 0.61034292763991205, 0.63832235955391514, None)
[[159  83   7   0]
 [  3 811   6   0]
 [  5  22 118   0]
 [  0   1   0   0]]




C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1074: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
```

The problem now is that I am getting a confusion matrix of 4x4 and I just have three labels so I would like to receive support here,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break things down to better understand the process:

1. In your original dataset, you have your input samples X, and the target classes Y (and from what I understood, you have three possible values here: 1, 2 and 3).
2. When train_test_split is called, your input samples and target classes are splitted, generating X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test.
3. You now have to **train your model using X_train et Y_train** (and that's the part with a misunderstanding in your code): `clf2 = clf2.fit(X_train, Y_train)`
4. Now that the model is properly trained on training data, you can actually test it on your test subsamples.

Doing so, you generate the **Y_pred** you are looking for :

```
Y_pred = clf2.predict(X_test)
```

Y_pred is a 1d array having for each element the class predicted by your model.
You know what the true value for these classes are: Y_test.

Your now have Y_true and Y_test, and can evaluate your classifier.

I hope it helped !

Comment: Yes I just would like to incorporate these two metrics, I mean recall and precision, since I am using train_test_split, and the topic of random state, I am very confusing about this fact, I would like to appreciate support to incorporate these two metrics.

Comment: my main question is how to get what are the values of my array called Y that contains the truth if I am using this method: train_test_split in order to finally use recall and precision metrics

Comment: your explanation was so useful however after trying to créate the confussion matrix I am getting a 4x4 matrix, I just have three labels 1,2,3 so I would like to appreciate support, thanks for your support,

Comment: Weird, as apparently only this 4th "label" only appears once. Maybe an error in the input data ?
To check the different values in y_true and y_pred, could you try to print set(y_true) and set(y_pred) ?

Comment: I tried printing this information, print(y_test)
print(y_pred), but is not so informative [1 1 0 ..., 1 1 2]
[1 1 0 ..., 1 1 2] since there is a lot of data

Comment: You forgot the set() : print(set(y_test)) and print(set(y_pred)), to only display the distinct values :).

Comment: {0, 1, 2, 3}
{0, 1, 2} , this is the result I have four values print(set(y_test))
print(set(y_pred)) in the y_test it seems like a data error,

Comment: the problem is now how to clean the data and to identify where is this value that is presented one time